# JQuery slideDown() Issue With My Need

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Designing a website which involves slideDown.

Initially i have set up a template which looks like the image below[image: SlideDownBefore]

When i hover over each black blocks a ul list will be displayed... But a problem arises when i hover... All the content below the block moves down (This is illustrated in the following figure)

[image: After SlideDown]

I cant give the position to be absolute because all the content above and below are floating (They Don't have a fixed height). So what else can be done to get a slideDown by holding the rest of content there and by displaying the hover content over the text?

Comment: Have you tried placing each block on a unique z-index?

Comment: @Jay Op didn't understand where and how to use absolutely positioned elements in combination with floats, so obviously no

Comment: i'm not trying to use a float... i mean the content above this doesnt have a fixed height... they expand with content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you should slideDown() an inner submenu element instead of the block itself. 
Consider this sample markup:

```
​<div class="item" id="mybox">floating box
    <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        <li>Subitem 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>More content... Just to illustrate</p>
<p>More content... Just to illustrate</p>​​​​​​
```

The CSS would be something like:

```
.​item {
    position: relative; /* to hold absolutely positioned submenu inside */
    background: #2684b7;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

    .item .submenu {
        position: absolute; /* the menu would go on top of everything */
        background: #2684b7;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }

p {
    clear: both;
}
```

And finally the JavaScript is simple, just don't forget to bulletproof your animation:
​

```
$('#mybox').hover(
    function() { /* mouseover */
        $(this).find('.submenu').slideDown();
    }, 
    function() { /* mouseout */
        $(this).find('.submenu').slideUp();
    }​​​​​
);
```

Here's the example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxrvC/

Good luck.
​

​

Comment: the thing is i cant afford it to be positioned absolutely... All content are floating... they dont have a fixed width...

Comment: What do you mean? My solution doesn't have fixed width. An absolutely positioned element shrinks to fit the content inside it. I only position the popup menu relatively to it's parent block.

Comment: Have you actually tried my solution? If it doesn't work, please provide an example when it fails.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry... Your Solution has partially worked :-)... Only Problem is the effect of slow slideDown is not working... What should i do for that?

Comment: What do you mean? Just call slideDown('slow') or pass number of milliseconds to the function, what's not working?

Comment: I figured it out sir... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Make a div with position: relative and z-index:55 and inside that div add a new div with position: absolute and also give width. Hope this will solve.

Regards

iijb

Comment: the thing is i cant afford it to be positioned absolutely... All content are floating... they dont have a fixed width...